# How to append auto-incremented number for label text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am implementing an extend form function, in which there is a label text (marked in html) that I hope to include a number to increment.

So every time when a form is extended/cloned, the label text in the extended form shows Student 1, Student 2... accordingly. Can I be advised how to do that?

```js
var counter = 0;
function moreFields(val1, val2, val3) {
 counter++;
 var newField = document.getElementById(val1).cloneNode(true);
 newField.id = '';
 newField.style.display = 'block';
 var newFields = newField.querySelectorAll('[name], [id], [for]');
  for (var i=0;i<newFields.length;i++) {
      var theNames = newFields[i].name
      if (theNames)
       newFields[i].name = "data[" + val3 + "][" + counter + "][" + theNames + "]";
             var theNames2 = newFields[i].id;
             if (theNames2)
                     newFields[i].id = theNames2 + counter;
             var theNames3 = newFields[i].htmlFor;
             if (theNames3)
                     newFields[i].htmlFor = theNames3 + counter;
  }   
 var insertHere = document.getElementById(val2);
 insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newField,insertHere); 
}
```

```html
<span id="readroot" style="display: none">
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-3">
  Grade 6
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-3">
  Male
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
                <!-- Student number needs to increase when a new form is extended. -->
    <label>Student 1</label> 
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-6">
    <label for="display_student_1_grade">Grade</label>
    <div id="display_student_1_grade"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-6">
    <label for="display_student_1_gender">Gender</label>
    <div id="display_student_1_gender"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div> 
</div>
<input class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Remove" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);" />
</span>
<span id="writeroot"></span>  
<input class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="moreFields('readroot', 'writeroot', 'Student')" value="One More Student" />
```

Comment: can you create JSfiddle with your code..?

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work on JSfiddle. I am trying. Oh and not sure if it helps, I am referring to this function. Thank you! http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/domform.html

Comment: @AlvinMok I added a code snippet for you. Removed the `php` blocks and fixed the `<label for` missing an `=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question directly, you just need to find the appropriate `<label>` and update the `innerHTML` (see below).

However, what you are doing here can be achieved using the new HTML5 [template](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/) element without having to hide `<span>` elements. Additionally, you have to remember that when you *remove* a student, the counter isn't going to *decrease*, nor are the already added students going to update. If you want that kind of functionality, you may want to look into a Javascript MVVM, like [Angular](https://angularjs.org/).

```js
var counter = 0;
function moreFields(val1, val2, val3) {
 counter++;
 var newField = document.getElementById(val1).cloneNode(true);
 newField.id = '';
 newField.style.display = 'block';
        // Find the label here and update the innerHTML appropriately
        newField.querySelector(".col-lg-12 label").innerHTML = "Student " + counter;
 var newFields = newField.querySelectorAll('[name], [id], [for]');
  for (var i=0;i<newFields.length;i++) {
   var theNames = newFields[i].name
   if (theNames)
    newFields[i].name = "data[" + val3 + "][" + counter + "][" + theNames + "]";
   var theNames2 = newFields[i].id;
         if (theNames2)
             newFields[i].id = theNames2 + counter;
         var theNames3 = newFields[i].htmlFor;
         if (theNames3)
             newFields[i].htmlFor = theNames3 + counter;
  }   
 var insertHere = document.getElementById(val2);
 insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newField,insertHere); 
}
```

```html
<span id="readroot" style="display: none">
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-3">
  Grade 6
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-3">
  Male
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
                <!-- Student number needs to increase when a new form is extended. -->
    <label>Student 1</label> 
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-6">
    <label for="display_student_1_grade">Grade</label>
    <div id="display_student_1_grade"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-6">
    <label for="display_student_1_gender">Gender</label>
    <div id="display_student_1_gender"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div> 
</div>
<input class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Remove" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);" />
</span>
<span id="writeroot"></span>  
<input class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="moreFields('readroot', 'writeroot', 'Student')" value="One More Student" />
```

Comment: Thank you! I do need to make sure the numbers are deducted on remove. Can you be so kind to briefly give me a heads up what element or method or things I should look into on that website?

Comment: Angular is a large framework, quite a bit of a learning curve, but it's perfect for templating like this. Here's [a demo Todo app](http://todomvc.com/examples/angularjs/#/) with source code. Otherwise, every time you click on the remove button, you'll need to iterate all of the clones, find the label again & update the `innerHTML` accordingly